# how to perform join and retrive in web2py

Tags: join, web2py

```
db.define_table('Theatres' , 
            Field('Name'),
            Field('TID'),
            Field('NoOfScreen'),
            Field('Address'),
            Field('LocId'),
            Field('Contact'),
            )
db.define_table('Movie' , 
            Field('Name'),
            Field('MovieCast'),
            Field('Director'),
            Field('Duration'),
            Field('MovieLanguage'),
           )
 db.define_table('Shows' , 
            Field('Movie'),
            Field('TID',db.Theatres),
            Field('Timing'),
            Field('SID',db.Screen),
           )
```

I'm new to stackoverflow, please guide if any mistakes.
this is my database to book a movie ticket. Im having trouble getting the name #of the theatre once the movie name is selected.

How do I perform join on the given tables above. I get the movie name from the Movie table. I have to look up the TID from the Shows table and then retrieve the theatre Name using Shows.TID from Theatres table.
thanks in advance
this is my code for which I'm getting errors.

```
 row2=db((db.Shows.Movie==request.args(0))&   (db.Shows.TID==db.Theatres.TID)).select()
```

here from the `request.args(0)` I'm getting the movie name.

Comment: What are the errors you are getting?

Comment: I'm getting the following error<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>

Comment: Hey I got to know where I had gone wrong. It was a silly mistake from my side. Thanks a lot for responding @Rockbot

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping @bibi

Comment: If you found a solution to your problem share it.

Comment: I was importing the wrong csv file containing the data for the tables,hence the querying was not yeilding the desired result for me.sorry for the late reply.